# How do I define this predicate so that it doesn't run forever

Tags: prolog

I need to define a predicate such that:

```
?- X = succ(X), nu(X).
false.
```

How do I do it? It just seems like it won't return anything and just run forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
nu(0).
nu(S) :-
    acyclic_term(S),
    S = succ(X),
    nu(X).
```

The acyclic_term/1 call is necessary to fail in the first query.